Microsoft Store installation hangs

I've tried installing one or two (or a few) apps before from the Store, always gave up in exasperation and used products from other sources. The installation code simply hangs as soon  as it opens, having displayed this message.

@Gantendo: I probably don't understand you: If I install from almost anywhere else but the Store, I rarely experience any difficulties.


Let windows try to fix the Microsoft Store. Press Windows, type troublesh, and select Recommended troubleshooting. Select Additional troubleshooters, select  Windows Store Apps,  and run the troubleshooter.
Try fixing the Microsoft Store manually.

Check that the PC time is correct. (Connection encryption can be time-based, to prevent recording of a transaction and playing it back at a later time.)
Confirm that you are owner of the hidden folder ‪C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.
Purge the Windows Store cache. Press WindowsR, type wsreset and press Enter.
Reinstall the Microsoft Store.

Press Windows, type powersh, select powershell.exe, and press CtrlShiftEnter to run PowerShell as administrator.
Enter get-appxpackage -allusers -name Microsoft.WindowsStore.
Copy the PackageFullName to the clipboard (e.g., Microsoft.WindowsStore_22402.1401.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe).
Enter remove-appxpackage  followed by the pasted package name and press Enter to remove it.
Reboot the machine.
Reopen PowerShell as above and enter Get-AppXPackage *WindowsStore* -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"} to reinstall the Windows Store.*




Try repairing Windows with DISM and SFC.
Try reinstalling Windows 10 from ISO to repair the issue.

